# Returning to Android Development - Which test device / min SDK?

Tags: android, development-environment

I'm returning to Android Development after a number of years. I built some apps and sold them about 4 years ago but turned to the dark side (iOS dev).

**This is programming forum so my two questions are:**

**Whats the minimum SDK most people develop against?**

In iOS it's [(Current Release - 1) + last good release] so iOS9 - 1 = iOS8 + last good release 8.4.

**What's the best dev device to buy?**

Nexus?
I have a Motorola Moto G (3rd Gen) bought Sep 2015

Whats the most used Android phone?

Comment: once again the close votes and downvotes reminds why I stopped contributing to stackoverflow years ago. It's impossible to ask a reasonable question with out being shouted down. Thanks to the two than answered. I'll delete the question and leave now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily, Google just publish a new post yesterday about how to [pick your min sdk](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd#.b4f3nsp0x), I would recommend reading it first.

Answer (score 1):

This question is mostly primarily opinion-based, but I would suggest using minimum API 15.

96,8% of devices are using system with API 15 and above, based on data collected by Google.

[Dashboards](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)

---

About device, I would pick the one which provides the fastest updates to new version. Do some research when producers update their system in devices and then decide. I think Nexus 5X would be good pick.